# Lambda not resolving type

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I see a strange issue where eclipse is not dentifying my lambda arguments

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {23,43,56,97,32};
    int sum1 = Arrays.asList(array).stream().reduce(0, (total, e) -> total + e).intValue(); 
}
```

I get `total` and `e` cannot be resolved to a variable.
I see examples where 'total' and 'e' are used as arguments without declaring.
However,in my case - it refuses to compile without declaring.
What is the issue here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(array)` for a primitive array returns a `List` whose single element is that array.

Change

```
Arrays.asList(array).stream()
```

to

```
Arrays.stream(array)
```

Note this will give to an `IntStream`, not a `Stream<Integer>`, so no need for `intValue()` at the end:

```
int sum1 = Arrays.stream(array).reduce(0, (total, e) -> total + e);
```

For a `Stream<Integer>` you can write:

```
Arrays.stream(array).boxed()
```

and the full line will be:

```
int sum1 = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().reduce(0, (total, e) -> total + e).intValue ();
```

Of course you can simply obtain the sum with:

```
int sum1 = Arrays.stream(array).sum ();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Arrays.asList(int[]) - will create a List<int[]>
```

You should have it like this:

```
int sum1 = Arrays.asList(23, 43, 56, 97, 32)
                 .stream().reduce(0, (total, e) -> total + e).intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
int[] array = {23,43,56,97,32};
int sum1 = Arrays.stream(array).reduce(0, (total, e) -> total + e);
```

I've changed `Arrays.asList(...).stream()`, which produces `Stream<int[]>`, to `Arrays.stream(...)` (or `IntStream.of(...)`).

In addition to this you can simplify the reduction to:

```
int sum1 = Arrays.stream(array).sum();
```